# absolute positioned div within relative div doesn't want to extend with more content

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have my #content div and #box_left and #box_right inside of it. Parent div is positioned relatively, but both inner divs are positioned absolutely. Problem is that #box_right doesn't want to extend its height when there's more content inside. 
I wanted also those inner divs make static and floated to set them side by side, but content dissapear then even though I've set clear:both at #footer div.
Another small problem: do u know why menu links are stretching and last link is going to second line when page is scaled by screen resolution?

Here's link to my site: [CLICK HERE](http://www.portalpraktyk.pl/site)

Would appreciate any help!
Thnx in advance

Comment: Your #wrapper div gets a height of 250 set on it when the page loads which doesn't change when clicking your "go in" link.

Answer (score 1):

if the contents of the box that won't extend are floated, you need an additional div after them:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="box_right" style="margin-left:200px;"></div>
    <div id="box_left" style="float: left; width: 200px;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: footer which is after them has this property and it's not working :/

Comment: i don't know if you're working on it at present, but the box_right and box_left are absolutely positioned (not floated).  absolutely positioning divs takes them out of the flow of the DOM.  other things can't react to their size/etc. edit again

Comment: looks like you got it.  gratz!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your "height:100%" on #box_right and #content - they're not helping you.

Instead, set the min-height on the #content div to be slightly larger than the #box_right div, and you should be laughing. After removing the 100% heights, I set the min-height of #content to 1000px (all using the inspector in Chrome) and it renders properly.

I also had a quick look at your javascript - you should be storing all of your jQuery selectors as variables rather than re-querying them - it will be much faster. So your document.ready handler should be written more like this:

```
$(function () {
    var $content = $("#content");
    var $footer = $("#footer");

    $content.hide();
    // etc

    $("a", $footer).click(function () {
        $footer.animate({ marginTop: "none" }, 1000);
        // etc
    });

    // etc
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I`m trying to use absolute positioning on some "master objects".
Use "clear:both; position: relative; float:left; " on first div of the layout-row, "position: relative; float:left;" for the rest of them to align nicely left to right.
use "display: block;" on child-element to "fit" object dimensions to content inside it.

Nice tutorial about object positioning: [div boxes](http://www.wickham43.net/divboxes.php)

Answer (score -1):

Use a float based layout Unless you have a good reason to use absolutes you are just causing your own problems.

UPDATE:
An absolute positioned element is taken out of the flow of the document. Clear will have no effect. Clear only affects floated elements which is what you should probably be using. Or, look into flexbox which is awesome but has its own complexities.

[solved-by-flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)